# How to use comment like syntax for IE in html head tag?

Tags: xpages

How to use the comment like syntax for IE in html head tag? I specificaly mean this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>   <script src="json2.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

As xpages uses for comments the same syntax as html standard, this comment is not rendered in browser ... any idea work workaround?

Comment: maybe this link can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx#dlrevealed

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load specific resources (such as CSS or JS) only for IE versions up to and including 7, then you can do this in a theme:

```
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0, 7) == true}">
  <content-type>text/javascript</content-type>
  <href>json2.js</href>
</resource>
```

Notice the `context.getUserAgent().isIE()` method that without parameters returns true for IE and with parameters returns true for specific versions of IE.